# Bootstrap Grid alignment on small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just felt if this issue can be resolved with any css tweaks.

I have a row with Col -8 and Col -4 in it, Col -4 has the following 4 grid images in it with **two rows again in it**

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="four">
        <img src="images/home/client1.png" style="width:100% ; height:160px" alt="Devegowda">

        <div class="four-overlay top">
          <p style="font-weight: bold">HD Devegowda</p>
          <br /> Former Prime Minister of India (1996)
          <br />
          <a class="button_example" href="#">Read</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- <br />-->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="four">
        <img src="images/home/client1.png" style="width:100% ; height:160px" alt="Devegowda">

        <div class="four-overlay top">
          <p style="font-weight: bold">HD Bhawani</p>
          <br /> Former Prime Minister of India (1996)
          <br />
          <a class="button_example" href="#">Read</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="four">
        <img src="images/home/client1.png" style="width:100% ; height:160px" alt="Devegowda">

        <div class="four-overlay top">
          <p style="font-weight: bold">HD Revanna</p>
          <br /> Former Prime Minister of India (1996)
          <br />
          <a class="button_example" href="#">Read</a>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- <br />-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="four">
        <img src="images/home/client1.png" style="width:100% ; height:160px" alt="Devegowda">

        <div class="four-overlay top">
          <p style="font-weight: bold">HD Kumaraswamy</p>
          <br /> Former Prime Minister of India (1996)
          <br />
          <a class="button_example" href="#">Read</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It appears like this when I minimize the screen to check its mobile compatibility but it looks ugly as two images in each row getting merged like this, I feel it will be much better if there is a small padding between two images here, any help ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you will need to also specify the classes for different devices (col-sm-X  and col-xs-X  for tablets and phones).

If you prefer not to do that ... the COL-MD will be equal to COL-XS-12 no matter of its size.

So in order to display your images properly... you should add the class col-xs-4 or 6 for each image parent that already has the class: col-md-6   .

Hope it helps.

Comment: precisely...got it...awesome..works perfect now..will make sure that entire col -md in d website is also added with sm and xs

Answer (score 0):

From the bootstrap docs, try

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images